# How to redirect a user to a different user page based on their Login Credentials, using Ajax, PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am faced with a problem that involves redirecting a user to a different page based on their roles. I want to do this using Ajax-which will post the login data to a PHP script, that'll inquire from the server if the user exist and if this is true, the user should be redirected to his/her page,else the page should remain in the login section.

Here's a typical input form:

```
<p>Enter User Name <input type ="text" name ="login_id" /></p>

<p>Enter Password <input type ="password" name "user_pass"/></p>
<p>Select Login Option
<select name"log_desc" > 
    <option value ="">----</option>
    <option value ="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value ="jun_staff">Junior</option>
    <option value ="sen_staff">Senior Staff</option>
    <option value ="emp">Employee</option>
</select>

</p>
```

So as per the above script, the Admin should be validated and redirected to "./dashboard.html" for example, Junior should be validated and redirected to "./junstaff.html" and so forth.

It was easy to achieve having separate login pages (e.g a Login As page that redirects to a user-role Login page) but I'd like to try this with one login page.

So, for the Database we can have database named "admin" ← This carries list and details of all admins, a "jun_staff" database that has details for the Junior staff and all the login credentials.

The issue is the PHP code needed to redirect the user after successful authentication and post back to Ajax the page required.
I'd appreciate anyone's indulgence in to this matter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the Ajax code you have so far as a starting point. What is the particular problem you are having with it?

Comment: You don't usually need the user type drop-down, since this information is stored in the user table. Do you have a user table in your case, and does it have a column for user type?

Comment: "redirecting a user to a different page" … "using Ajax" — **stop!** Ajax is for when you want to communicate with the server **and** keep people *on the same page*. If you are going to send people to a new page, don't use Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to run 'redirection' you don't need to use AJAX..

You need this:

```
<select name"log_desc" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> 
    <option value ="">----</option>
    <option value ="admin.html">Admin</option>
    <option value ="jun_staff.html">Junior</option>
    <option value ="sen_staff.html">Senior Staff</option>
    <option value ="emp.html">Employee</option>
</select>
```